# ListView items as Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

I have a Layout which contains a `textview` and `editText` on the top, then after a `listView` and at the bottom i have `4 buttons`.

I want my listview items to contain a `imageView` and `4 textViews`.

I have the main layout with all the views in the 1st statement and a seperate `list_item.xml` (linear layout) which contains all the elements (imageview and 4 textviews) which each listview item must contain.

How can I populate the listview in my main layout with list_item.xml layout.

1. I  have populated a listview using a list_item.xml which contains only TextView tag (not a linear or relative layout).
2. I also populated some other listview using a custom array adapter, but here the main layout contains only the list view item layout but not the top textview and edit view and bottom 4 buttons.

I think my problem is a combination of both point1 and point2. can anyone explain how to achieve this?

Comment: please put the image what you exactly want.

Comment: i also think you have to put simple image of layout you want to achieve... and let your image focus mostly on LIST and LIST ITEMS, because your explanation was not 100% clear... You have to understand if people are putting their time into answering your question, they should at least be sure they are understanding it correctly... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a custom adapter like this...

```
  private class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<yourclass> {

    private ArrayList<yourclass> items;

    public myAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<yourclass> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }
            yourclass o = items.get(position);
            if (o != null) {
                    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                    TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        //similarly for 2 more textviews and a imageview
                    if (tt != null) {
                          tt.setText("Name: "+o.getitemName());                            }
                    if(bt != null){
                          bt.setText("Status: "+ o.getitemStatus());
             //similarly...and getitemName ,getitemStatus are functions of your class.. to get the values..
                    }
            }
            return v;
    }
```

}

Comment: here the adapter wants input parameter to be TextView Id only

Comment: i want it to be a layout which is a linearlayoput and contains a imageview and 4 text views.please help